# Cocos2d-x installed application can't be launched on android

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I am developing game using `cocos2d-x` I am succesfully playing it on `iOS`, `MacOS` and `win32` but at the moment I am having issue trying to launch it on android. Compilation and installation are completed I just can't launch it because of the problem I can't understand/see. Could someone help or hint me about the problem?

Info: testing on real device, Android version 4.4.4., cocos2d-x-3.13.1, c++, target 4.4.2, eclipse Neon.1a Release (4.6.1), mac os.

If additional information is required I can provide it.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.companyName.gameName"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0"
  android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon">

    <!-- Tell Cocos2dxActivity the name of our .so -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
               android:value="MyGame" />

    <activity android:name="org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

**LogCat (warn, error, assert):**

```
04-21 09:49:49.917: E/Watchdog(596): !@Sync 1245
04-21 09:49:52.780: W/AlarmManager(596): Set alarm: type= 3 triggerAtTime= 143810266 , called by : com.google.android.gms, intent:Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.lockbox.LockboxAlarmReceiver }
04-21 09:49:59.997: W/AlarmManager(596): Set alarm: type= 3 triggerAtTime= 143817481 , called by : android, intent:Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x50000000 }
04-21 09:50:00.157: W/ResourceType(2304): Failure getting entry for 0x010400da (t=3 e=218) in package 0 (error -75)
04-21 09:50:00.157: E/accuweather(2304): [AccuTab_Magagine]>>> UIMK:1463 [0:0] time : 08:50
04-21 09:50:00.177: W/ResourceType(2304): Failure getting entry for 0x010400da (t=3 e=218) in package 0 (error -75)
04-21 09:50:19.917: E/Watchdog(596): !@Sync 1246
04-21 09:50:36.803: W/ContextImpl(25935): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity:1255 android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity:330 android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity:330 com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpReceiver$3.handleMessage:786 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102 
04-21 09:50:36.813: W/ContextImpl(25935): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity:1267 android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity:1256 android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity:330 android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity:330 com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpReceiver$3.handleMessage:786 
04-21 09:50:37.033: W/ActivityManager(596): mDVFSHelper.acquire()
04-21 09:50:37.043: E/MTPRx(25935): started activity for popup
04-21 09:50:37.154: W/ApplicationPackageManager(25935): getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 09:50:37.204: E/SettingsReceiverActivity(25935): PREF_DONT_ASK_AGAIN : true
04-21 09:50:37.214: W/InputMethodManagerService(596): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@42ef9528 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@42a655d8
04-21 09:50:38.084: W/ApplicationPackageManager(596): getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 09:50:40.036: W/ActivityManager(596): mDVFSHelper.release()
04-21 09:50:49.916: E/Watchdog(596): !@Sync 1247
04-21 09:50:52.789: W/AlarmManager(596): Set alarm: type= 3 triggerAtTime= 144530276 , called by : android, intent:Intent { act=android.net.ConnectivityService.action.PKT_CNT_SAMPLE_INTERVAL_ELAPSED flg=0x4000000 }
04-21 09:50:52.849: W/AlarmManager(596): Set alarm: type= 3 triggerAtTime= 143870336 , called by : com.google.android.gms, intent:Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.lockbox.LockboxAlarmReceiver }
04-21 09:50:59.996: W/AlarmManager(596): Set alarm: type= 3 triggerAtTime= 143877482 , called by : android, intent:Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x50000000 }
04-21 09:51:00.076: W/ResourceType(2304): Failure getting entry for 0x010400da (t=3 e=218) in package 0 (error -75)
04-21 09:51:00.076: E/accuweather(2304): [AccuTab_Magagine]>>> UIMK:1463 [0:0] time : 08:51
04-21 09:51:00.096: W/ResourceType(2304): Failure getting entry for 0x010400da (t=3 e=218) in package 0 (error -75)
04-21 09:51:03.719: E/memtrack(26128): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
04-21 09:51:03.719: E/android.os.Debug(26128): failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-21 09:51:03.900: W/ActivityManager(596): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/MyGame.apk
04-21 09:51:19.915: E/Watchdog(596): !@Sync 1248
04-21 09:51:30.275: W/ApplicationPackageManager(25304): getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 09:51:42.527: W/ActivityManager(596): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/MyGame.apk
04-21 09:51:43.588: E/PackageManager(596): parse pkg : /data/app/vmdl276537072.tmp
04-21 09:51:43.618: E/PackageManager(596): dexopt start
04-21 09:51:44.980: E/PackageManager(596): dexopt end
04-21 09:51:49.915: E/Watchdog(596): !@Sync 1249
04-21 09:51:53.068: W/AlarmManager(596): Set alarm: type= 3 triggerAtTime= 143930557 , called by : com.google.android.gms, intent:Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.lockbox.LockboxAlarmReceiver }
04-21 09:51:56.111: W/PackageManager(596): verifying app can be installed or not
04-21 09:51:56.331: W/PackageManager(596): Not granting permission android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER to package com.companyName.GameName (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be46)
04-21 09:51:56.511: W/ApplicationPackageManager(596): getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 09:51:56.561: W/ApplicationPackageManager(596): getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 09:51:56.771: W/ApplicationPackageManager(596): getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 09:51:56.781: W/ApplicationPackageManager(930): getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 09:51:56.781: W/ApplicationPackageManager(930): getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 09:51:56.781: E/SamsungIME(1471): mOCRHelper is null
04-21 09:51:56.941: W/ApplicationPackageManager(951): getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 09:51:58.343: W/ApplicationPackageManager(1195): getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 09:51:58.453: E/EdmStorageProvider(596): Admin not in database, something went wrong
04-21 09:51:59.103: W/AlarmManager(596): Set alarm: type= 0 triggerAtTime= 1492761134119 , called by : com.android.vending, intent:Intent { cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.services.ContentSyncService }
04-21 09:51:59.344: W/IcingInternalCorpora(1352): getNumBytesRead when not calculated.
04-21 09:51:59.354: E/memtrack(26153): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
04-21 09:51:59.354: E/android.os.Debug(26153): failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-21 09:51:59.504: E/Finsky(25304): [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(847): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
04-21 09:51:59.814: W/ActivityManager(596): mDVFSHelper.acquire()
04-21 09:51:59.994: W/AlarmManager(596): Set alarm: type= 3 triggerAtTime= 143937482 , called by : android, intent:Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x50000000 }
04-21 09:52:00.215: W/ActivityManager(596): Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=26179, uid=10129 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
04-21 09:52:00.245: W/ApplicationPackageManager(26179): getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 09:52:00.275: W/ActivityManager(596): Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=26179, uid=10129 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
04-21 09:52:00.615: E/JniHelper(26179): Failed to find static java method. Class name: (null), method name: getCocos2dxPackageName, signature: ()Ljava/lang/String; 
04-21 09:52:00.615: W/ResourceType(2304): Failure getting entry for 0x010400da (t=3 e=218) in package 0 (error -75)
04-21 09:52:00.625: A/libc(26179): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xfffffff4 (code=1), thread 26179 (peFromTheIsland)
04-21 09:52:00.635: E/accuweather(2304): [AccuTab_Magagine]>>> UIMK:1463 [0:0] time : 08:52
04-21 09:52:00.645: W/ResourceType(2304): Failure getting entry for 0x010400da (t=3 e=218) in package 0 (error -75)
04-21 09:52:00.865: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(1352): A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+data+com_google_android_gms+databases+metrics_db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
04-21 09:52:00.875: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(1352): A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+data+com_google_android_gms+databases+help_responses_db_18' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
04-21 09:52:00.875: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(1352): A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+data+com_google_android_gms+databases+auto_complete_suggestions_db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
04-21 09:52:00.875: W/ApplicationPackageManager(1352): getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 09:52:01.165: W/ActivityManager(596):   Force finishing activity com.companyName.GameName/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity
04-21 09:52:01.206: W/ApplicationPackageManager(596): getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 09:52:01.216: W/ApplicationPackageManager(596): getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 09:52:01.516: E/android.os.Debug(596): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -m 26179 -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
04-21 09:52:01.596: W/ContextImpl(596): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1372 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.broadcastEvent:296 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.processDropBoxEntry:254 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.access$100:60 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector$1.onReceive:102 
04-21 09:52:01.716: W/ActivityManager(596): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{425a2d00 u0 com.companyName.GameName/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity t89 f}
04-21 09:52:01.906: W/ActivityManager(596): mDVFSHelper.release()
04-21 09:52:02.577: W/ApplicationPackageManager(596): getCSCPackageItemText()
```

**LogCat (Filtered for application (Full)):**

```
04-21 09:52:00.185: D/ActivityThread(26179): handleBindApplication:com.companyName.gameName
04-21 09:52:00.245: W/ApplicationPackageManager(26179): getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 09:52:00.265: D/DisplayManager(26179): DisplayManager()
04-21 09:52:00.305: D/dalvikvm(26179): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.companyName.gameName-1/libMyGame.so 0x41ccab70
04-21 09:52:00.615: E/JniHelper(26179): Failed to find static java method. Class name: (null), method name: getCocos2dxPackageName, signature: ()Ljava/lang/String; 
04-21 09:52:00.625: A/libc(26179): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xfffffff4 (code=1), thread 26179 (peFromTheIsland)
```

Comment: Are you calling `getCocos2dxPackageName` method from c++ through jni ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I do not think I am calling it.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I haven't wrote it. Can it be because I am using sqlite or something with package name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by `extern` `Userdefaults` in `Constants`. To fix it I changed (`Constants.cpp`):

```
cocos2d::UserDefault *userDefaults = cocos2d::UserDefault::getInstance();
```

`Constants.hpp`:

```
extern cocos2d::UserDefault *userDefaults;
```

> To:

`Constants.cpp`

```
cocos2d::UserDefault *userDefaults;
```

And (`AppDelegate.cpp`)

```
userDefaults = cocos2d::UserDefault::getInstance();
```

Have not done any changes to `Constants.hpp`.
Permissions is not required and also were was no problem with package name.

Logcat messages was not helpfull...

Comment: Have you figured out what is the problem in `extern cocos2d::UserDefault *userDefaults;`

Comment: you mean to removing `INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER` and adding `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL` permission is not helpful for you ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I tracked this problem on new project without the those permission and it worked. I just said that LogCat errors was not helpfull at all. Problem was with **cocos2d::UserDefault::getInstance();** in **Constants.cpp** file so I just moved it to **AppDelegate** but I do not know why it was happening.

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER"/>
```

remove this permission from `Manifest` file. you can only use `normal` and `Dangerous` permission.

A third-party developer cannot grant to his/her application the permission required to install a new location provider `(android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER)`. Only OEMs are allowed to install a new location provider.

**EDIT**

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

**EDIT**

check package name I see `com.companyName.gameName` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, you are running your app using package  `com.companyName.GameName` and `AppActivity` is in `org.cocos2dx.cpp`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143612/discussion-on-answer-by-abhishek-aryan-cocos2d-x-installed-application-cant-be).